# Why does Android dislike to see implementation of the constructor of an activity?

Tags: android

My `activity` contains a `TabHost` , and I implemented the `constructor` of the `activity`. At runtime the app crashed ! So I removed the implementation of the `constructor` and the app run successfully ! So why and when should we implement the `constructor` of an `activity` ?

Comment: cannot get logcat cause I run the app on a tablet which has a notfound driver.

Comment: android's basics - activity life cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, Activities are initialised by the system through ClassLoader, who is requiring public non-argument constructor in order to initialise the object.

Normally, you never override/add constructor for activities in Android.
If really want to do it, however, you must implement public non-argument constructor.

Look at the documentation for more details how this class works:
[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)